# Launch Android Google Maps in directions mode, with "Avoid Highways"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, directions

In my Android app, I am trying to launch Google Maps in directions mode with "Avoid Highways" selected.

Using this code, I can launch Gmaps in turn-by-turn mode with "Avoid Highways":

```
public void openMapsApp(String destinationCoords)
{
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+destinationCoords+"&avoid=h");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

However, I want to launch Gmaps in directions mode, not turn-by-turn navigation mode. I want to do this because I want the user to be able to quickly change their destination without having to exit out of navigation mode first.

In my attempt at doing this, I change one line to:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://maps.google.com/?saddr=My+location&daddr="+destinationCoords+"&dirflg=h");
```

And this does launch Gmaps into directions mode. However, for some strange reason, `dirflg=h` stops working. This URL does set 'avoid highways' to true when I open it in a web browser, but for some reason it doesn't when I launch Gmaps.

What's extra strange is that in my app if I use a different value like `dirflg=w` or `dirflg=r` it launches Gmaps in walking and transit directions, respectively. It's only `dirflg=h` that doesn't work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I resolved it by using `dirflg=dh` !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I resolved it by using `dirflg=dh` !!!!